# Symbol Not found using enum

Tags: java, enums

I am an experienced programmer but new to Java. I have defined an enum but getting "Symbol not found" when I attempt to use it. I have looked at many answers and they all point to naming conflicts. I have renamed my enum but no luck still. After further research I found the following example on an Oracle website. (Note, I broke naming convention to ensure that "Day" did not present a naming conflict)

```
public enum Day__ {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
}
```

As the example suggests, I tried to use it in the following way:

```
public class EnumTest {
    Day__ day;

    public EnumTest(Day__ day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Yet on compile (using Intellij) I get the following:

```
Error:(7, 5) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Day__
  location: class com.islbahamas.firstcontact.client.EnumTest
```

Following Jon and Janos' advice (which I really appreicate), I created a whole new project (TestProject). In the path C:\Dev\TestProject\src\com\islbahamas\completelyNewPackageInNewProject I have the following two files:
Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName.java
TestEnum.java

Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName.java looks like this:

```
package com.islbahamas.completelyNewPackageInNewProject;

/**
 * Created by Clyde on 12/7/2014.
 */
public enum Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
                THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
    }
```

and TestEnum.java looks like this:

```
package com.islbahamas.completelyNewPackageInNewProject;

/**
 * Created by Clyde on 12/7/2014.
 */
public class TestEnum {
    Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName day;

    public TestEnum(Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

note ... same package for both

Error: 
Error:(7, 5) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName
  location: class com.islbahamas.completelyNewPackageInNewProject.TestEnum

Even with the import (albeit unnecessary) statement include (as shown below), I have the same error

```
package com.islbahamas.completelyNewPackageInNewProject;

import com.islbahamas.completelyNewPackageInNewProject.Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName;
/**
 * Created by Clyde on 12/7/2014.
 */
public class TestEnum {
    Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName day;

    public TestEnum(Day_OnlyClassDefinedWithThisName day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what package is `Day__` declared in?

Comment: Jon Day__ is declared in package com.islbahamas.firstcontact.client;

Comment: And is it in the classpath for where you're trying to compile the test code? (You haven't told us anything about how you're compiling etc.)

Comment: Jon. I am sorry.  Yes, same class path

Comment: And the enum isn't declared within another class? Please give all the details of how you're compiling, what your environment is etc.

Comment: Jon. No. It is not declared within another class. I encountered this error while developing an application for a client. To isolate its cause I posted the sample code into an old working learning project. I am using Intellij IDEA 13.1.6. Project SDK 1.8. Java EE7

Comment: @Tom: Nope, I misread somehow. Not sure how... Will kill my comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok :). But you're right, this question is missing a lot of context. Clyde, can you please add a screenshot of your IntelliJ that shows your current class structure, especially where each class is located?

Comment: Tom. I tried to do that, but StackOverflow tells me that since I don't have 10 points (just signed up today), I can't post a pic.

Comment: Please check the following setting for me: Click in the menu on `File` and then on `Project Structure`. Choose `Modules` in the left list and then click on `Sources` (it is a tab beneth the module name textfield). Check that the `src` folder is *blue*. I get the same error message like you get, if I remove the `Sources` mark from the `src` folder and set it to a subdirectory, for example `com`. It should look like [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/G92e7Zb.png).

Comment: Tom. It is blue already :). I reset it, but problem persists

Answer (score 0):

If the files containing your enum and the test class, `Day__.java`, and `EnumTest.java` are inside the same directory, then this should work. If they are in different directories,
then in `EnumTest` you need to add an `import` statement near the top with the full package name of `Day__`, for example:

```
import path.to.Day__;
```

From the error message it's clear that `EnumTest` is in the package `com.islbahamas.firstcontact.client`, and since the compiler cannot find `Day__` in that same package, that means the `Day__.java` file must be somewhere else.

Comment: Janos. I tried that already :) ... Does not work. I will modify and post modified code

Comment: Well look, the problem is really simple: the `EnumTest` class doesn't know where to find `Day__`. You need to look at your project, observe where your files are, and add an appropriate `import` statement. If you still don't see the problem, add in your post the directory layout of your files, for example like the `tree` command in Linux.

Comment: @ClydeSymonette so how is this going?

Comment: Janos. I appreciate your follow up and sorry for my late response.  That scenario that I posted is not going despite anything I try!